# Android sending data from one application to another application

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service, intentfilter

I am working on a app,in which i have a requirement that send some string like "HelloWorld" from one application to another,how i can achieve this?please some expert software engineer help me out.

Comment: do you mean to say sending that string to "your" another app or "any" other app?

Comment: @MehulJoisar yes i want to send string lik "Helloworld" from one app to another..

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done this by the following link:

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html